# R package to get the colors of the image

Tags: r, colors

looking for an R package,where you give an image to the package and it will give the top 4 colors in that image. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `extract_colours()` function in the `rPlotter` package. You may find [this article](http://www.mepheoscience.com/colourful-ecology-part-1-extracting-colours-from-an-image-and-selecting-them-using-community-phylogenetics-theory/) helpful.

Comment: Thanks a ton George,that helped ! Is there way we can get Pixel fraction for this?